# Recover a method after a screen rotation on android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, rotation, screen

I read that after a screen rotation, an android activity is created again. I understood how to recover a view, but i don't understand if i can start from where a method was stopped after a screen rotation.

Comment: your method is not stopped when the screen rotates.

Comment: @njzk2 As the Activity is destroyed, how can this be true?

Comment: But if the activity is created again, how is it saved? The problem is that i must block the screen rotation if i can't recover the method that was stopped.

Comment: @Simon : a method is never 'stopped' during its execution, unless a/ it returns itself b/ an exception is raised. In the case of blocking calls, such as networking, it is possible to provoque the raising of the exception by calling thread.intercept. The exception can still be caught in the method body, and discarded. No one can force a method to stop, unless killing the whole process.

Comment: Thanks @njzk2  I had never thought about it before and it's so obvious when I do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recover after screen rotation.

In it's simplest form you save what you need to recreate where you left off in the onSaveInstanceState method.  So for your basic flashlight you save the state of the light.  For you more complex apps your saving all of the global fields.  Flashlight has a global variable isFlashOn.

```
private boolean isFlashOn = false;
```

save the state of the flashlight in the onSaveInstanceState

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean(ISON, isFlashOn);
}
```

Then in the oncreate method you recreate the global variable.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        isFlashOn = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(ISON);
    }
```

later in the onstart method process the isFlashOn.  This flashlight is turned on by a click so I change the state of isFlashOn and call the click handler.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart(); // Always call the superclass method first

    if (camera == null) {
        camera = Camera.open();
    }
            //flip the isflashon and then click the button
    isFlashOn = !isFlashOn;
    onClick(null);
}
```

process the click.

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    ImageButton i = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

    final Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
    if (isFlashOn) {
        i.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        isFlashOn = false;
        p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
    } else {
        i.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher2);
        p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(p);
        // Set flag to true
        camera.startPreview();
        isFlashOn = true;
    }
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

If there was a method that was executing at the moment you turned your screen, the method will finish its work.

It wont be paused or anything else since its "impossible" to do that.

If that particular method was important to your app/activity you should then call it again upon Activity recreation.

Comment: But if it's a mehthod that save some important value and it's not paused, then i can't rotate the screen

Comment: I didn understand what you just said? You can always rotate the screen unless you block it for that activity. It doesnt matter what the method is doing it will do its work even if you rotate the screen, check njzk2 comment for a nice explanation.

Comment: In such cases when you rotated the screen and for example you had a Thread that was working on downloading data from a web service, you should stop that thread , and start it again once its recreated ;) .